# Error durante la instalación de FastApi en termux (con android 11)

Tags: python, android, pip

Tengo el siguiente error en la instalación de muchos paquetes en termux (en este caso FastApi)

```
Running `rustc --crate-name build_script_build /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-1cd66030c949c28d/stacker-0.1.15/build.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debug-assertions=off -C metadata=1343b3d01f73d46c -C extra-filename=-1343b3d01f73d46c --out-dir /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-vuf9u3_u/maturin_467cd99f4f8843f49ea4bd69c88fec8e/target/release/build/stacker-1343b3d01f73d46c -L dependency=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-vuf9u3_u/maturin_467cd99f4f8843f49ea4bd69c88fec8e/target/release/deps --extern cc=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-vuf9u3_u/maturin_467cd99f4f8843f49ea4bd69c88fec8e/target/release/deps/libcc-acb5426da2feecff.rlib --cap-lints allow`
            error: failed to run custom build command for `psm v0.1.21`

            Caused by:
              process didn't exit successfully: `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-vuf9u3_u/maturin_467cd99f4f8843f49ea4bd69c88fec8e/target/release/build/psm-742d95307b2e4960/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
```

...

```
error occurred: Failed to find tool. Is `arm-linux-androideabi-ar` installed?


            warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
            error: `cargo build --manifest-path Cargo.toml --message-format=json-render-diagnostics --release -v --no-default-features --locked` failed with code 101
            [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for maturin
      Failed to build maturin
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for maturin, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
u0_a249@localhost ~ [1]>
```